# Why am I getting a load error during pod init in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Im building a social media app using Xcode. After running pod init im getting the error-

> **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/executor/cached_thread_pool (LoadError)**`

I've tried running sudo gem install concurrent executor cached thread pool with this result

```
**Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing concurrent:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-0.2.2/ext/concurrent/futures
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200311-6507-4x4g6z.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-0.2.2/ext/concurrent/futures
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-0.2.2/ext/concurrent/futures
make "DESTDIR="
compiling futures.c
In file included from futures.c:10:
/Users/davidstreet/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: rubysig.h is obsolete [-W#warnings]
#warning rubysig.h is obsolete
 ^
futures.c:11:10: fatal error: 'intern.h' file not found
#include "intern.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [futures.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-0.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/concurrent-0.2.2/gem_make.out
Successfully installed executor-0.0.1
Parsing documentation for executor-0.0.1
Done installing documentation for executor after 0 seconds
Successfully installed cached-0.2
Parsing documentation for cached-0.2
Done installing documentation for cached after 0 seconds
Successfully installed thread-0.2.2
Parsing documentation for thread-0.2.2
Done installing documentation for thread after 0 seconds
Successfully installed pool-0.0.1
Parsing documentation for pool-0.0.1
Done installing documentation for pool after 0 seconds
4 gems installed
davidstreet@Davids-MacBook-Pro lnc.xcodeproj %**
```

I'm new to app development so any help would be awesome. Could anyone tell me if this is a bug I could download a pre-release and work around?

Answer (score 0):

Use these command

```
gem install thread
```

And

```
gem install pool
```

Hope this will be useful

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried this with no success. Still getting the.       1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/executor/cached_thread_pool (LoadError)